# Нету подсветки ошибок для JS в VS code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Я нарочно сделал ошибку в коде, где фаааа должно подсвечиваться красной волнистой линией, а этого не происходит.[image: Скриншот]

Comment: настройте линтер или в первой строке файла напишите // @ts-chech